# Recovering lost files

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery

I have made a terrible mistake at work. So, I was supposed to install a fresh copy of win10
like I’ve done a milion times before, and I had to convert it to GPT since I had the 
MBR error. And in the rush I mistakenly performed the clean function on diskpart. 
So, the pc had 2 partitions of almost equall storage (~500GB), and please don’t
ask why but the only backup of the important files was on the second partition.
Of course I panicked, and without thinking it through I didn’t perform a recovery right
away, rather I finished with the installation and performed a recovery using EaseUS
, and when it finished, all the files were corrupted. Now, realizing the stupidity 
I formated and deleted the 2nd partition, extended the main (C:) to it’s original
900GB storage and performed another recovery session. Now, it’s currently in
progress and will last for another few hours. In case THAT doesn’t help, what are my 
options here? Are the files lost forever or what?

Comment: If the files could have been restored then your first attempt would have been successful.  All your doing is making professional data recovery less possible.  But you shouldn’t cancel the current operation since the damage as already happened

Comment: The first attempt did recover them but I couldn’t open any of them, like they were corrupted. Thats why I deleted the recovered files, deleted the 2nd part. and extended the 1st to its original size and started the second attempt of data recovery.

Comment: Every write or deleted file will significantly decrease your ability to restore files. Hopefully you didn’t restore files to the same HDD as your trying to recover from

Comment: Yeah...not that I didn't know but more like at this point I hoped that it wasn't like it. And yeah...it's the same drive. Well...nothing to do but hope for the best. I am assuming nothing else can be done here right? The reason I am asking is that I need to be 100% certain that at some point everyone will have to accept the fact that certain files are lost and gone forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update this question.

As it turns out, returning/formating to the original partition parameters **did help**, and almost all of the files were fully recovered (corruption rate was below 1%).